# capistrano deployment - basic commands fail

Tags: capistrano

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://de.slideshare.net/mauricio.linhares/deploying-your-rails-application-to-a-clean-ubuntu-10) to setup a rails stack with nginx, unicorn and capistrano on ubuntu (12.10). I decided to use RVM for ruby installation.

What I installed so far:

- all dependent libraries (imagemagick, git, mysql-server, etc.)
- nginx (1.2.1)
- rvm (1.17) and ruby (1.9.2)
- gems: rails (3.1.6), unicorn (4.4.0), capistrano (2.13.5), ...

Locally, I entered

```
$ capify .
```

that worked (on the deployment guide mentioned on the top, its on page 8)

But I'm stuck at the next part 'cap deploy:setup' (on the guide, page 12):

```
$ cap deploy:setup
/Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:26:in `set': you must specify exactly one of either a value or a block (ArgumentError)
  from ./config/deploy.rb:4:in `load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
  from Capfile:4:in `load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `block in load_recipes'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/bin/cap:19:in `load'
  from /Users/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@shop/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
```

And it seems that it doesn't depened on deploy:setup.

I tried out randomly some other capistrano commands and I get always the same error message 'you must specify exactly one of either a value or a block (ArgumentError)'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

It was a stupid mistake, I had twice 'set :scm, :git' in my deploy.rb.